# error logged in location other than specified

Tags: log4j

I am trying to log my error messages in a txt file using log4j.
The file is getting stored in the place where eclipse is installed rather than the destination i am specifying.
Please provide inputs.
this is the configuration i have done in .properties file.

```
log4j.rootlogger=DEBUG,DemoServlet
log4j.appender.DemoServlet= org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DemoServlet.file ./projname/src/log/ErrorLogFile.txt
log4j.appender.DemoServlet.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.DemoServlet.layout = org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `=` in the line:

```
log4j.appender.DemoServlet.file=./projname/src/log/ErrorLogFile.txt
```

Comment: is the path correct ? does log4j has permission to write the file ?